# Cannot use Crystal Reports 2008 report from Delphi 4 on more than one database

Tags: sql-server, delphi, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, delphi-4

I've converted a bunch of reports from Crystal Reports 7 to Crystal Reports 2008 as part of a migration from ASE (Sybase) to MS SQL Server. I also verified it via the "Set Database Location" option in Crystal Reports 2008.  When I converted the reports I pointed them to one of my test databases (let's call this DB_a).  I call these reports from a Delphi 4 application and it works fine.  The thing now is that when I try and run this report for another database (let's say DB_b) it gives an error: "Error: 723 Error in file reportname Execute ".

If I go back to Crystal 2008 and verify the report against DB_b it works fine on DB_b but gives the error on DB_a.  I compiled the same stored procedure that the report uses on both databases and the data that it returns is the same on both called from the back-end.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Set Dataset location.  You need to set the Overridden Qualified table Name: to the same name as the value in Table Name:

Thought it is possible that it does not need to be the same name just some name.  That is just what we do to keep it consistant.

All our reports are based off stored procedures.

So if Table Name: rptAP0100:1
The Overriden Qualified Table Name: dbo.rptAP0100;1

I am not sure why Crystal is not smart enough to know.  However I asked there support this very same question a few years back.